# VSCode/Pylint can't find module in same directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
└── src
    ├── config.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main.py
```

The content of `config.py` is:

```
FOO = 'bar'
```

The content of `main.py` is:

```
import config

print(config.FOO)
```

The `__init__.py` is empty.

With the above setup, VSCode\Pylint is complaining that `config has no FOO member`.

If I delete the `__init__.py` the warning disappears.

Why is this happening and what is the correct way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

It's happening because `import config` is an *absolute* import which means Python is trying to find `config` as a top-level package or module. But when you have an `__init__.py` file you make your `src/` directory a package, so that makes Python treat `src/config.py` not as `config` but as `src.config`. When you delete the `__init__.py`, the Python extension for VS Code assumes you want your `src/` directory to just be treated as a folder where you keep code and thus does extra work so Python runs from with `src/` and not the top of your workspace.